# How to sequentially add dummies while respecting groupby rule in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

| id | stage |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | stage 1 |
| 1 | stage 2 |
| 1 | stage 4 |
| 1 | stage 6 |
| 2 | stage 2 |
| 2 | stage 3 |
| 2 | stage 5 |
| 2 | stage 6 |

I was to generate dummy variables row by row and have the previous rows dummy values roll over.

The expected output should look something like this

| id | stage 1 | stage 2 | stage 3 | stage 4 | stage 5 | stage 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the stage to `pd.get_dummies` setting `id` as index, then groupby `level=0`, and call `cummax` on the groupby object, finally reset the index if needed.

```py
pd.get_dummies(df.set_index(['id'])['stage']).groupby(level=0).cummax().reset_index()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
   id  stage 1  stage 2  stage 3  stage 4  stage 5  stage 6
0   1        1        0        0        0        0        0
1   1        1        1        0        0        0        0
2   1        1        1        0        1        0        0
3   1        1        1        0        1        0        1
4   2        0        1        0        0        0        0
5   2        0        1        1        0        0        0
6   2        0        1        1        0        1        0
7   2        0        1        1        0        1        1
```

Comment: @Patelra95 you might consider accepting the answer to this question by clicking the checkmark to the left of this answer. This will let others know this question is solved. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more information.